# Object formatting - .map is removing my first line

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm altering an objects data using a .map function.

The original object that's values im trying to change, it loses it's first line which ruins the formatting for me. It is only the first line i lose, i think because it's not included somehow in my function?

The object:

```
graphData = {

"name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement1",
          "members": [{
              "id": "e334", "account": {
                  "id": "eefe" 
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3434",
              "positionTitle": "Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "landscaping",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "engagement1343",
    "members": [{
      "position": {
        "id": "4545",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Manager"

      }
      }]
     }]
    }
   ]
},

{
"name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement346",
          "members": [{
              "id": "34", "account": {
                  "id": "3546" 
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3999434",
              "positionTitle": "Ultime Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "Juicing",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "347343",
    "members": [{
        "id": "4546", "account": {
            "id": "3545"
        },
      "position": {
        "id": "35006",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Ultimate Manager"

      }
    }]
}]
 }]
}]
}
```

This is the function I use to alter the data fields (positionTitle)

```
   const a = realGraphData.engagementAreas.map((el, i) => {
        el.engagementTypes.forEach((et) => {
           et.engagements.forEach((eg) => {
              eg.members.forEach((mem) => {
                 mem.position.positionTitle = 'abc'

              });
           });
        });

        return el;
      })
```

My expected result should be:

```
{
    "name": "Annual meetings",
    "engagementAreas": [{
        "id": "1",
        "engagementTypes": [{
            "name": "forestry",
            "engagements": []
        }, {
            "name": "houses",
            "engagements": [{
                "name": "engagement1",
                "members": [{
                    "id": "e334",
                    "account": {
                        "id": "eefe"
                    },
                    "position": {
                        "id": "3434",
                        "positionTitle": "abc"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "landscaping",
            "engagements": [{
                "name": "engagement1343",
                "members": [{
                    "position": {
                        "id": "4545",
                        "positionTitle": "abc"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "community days",
        "engagementTypes": [{
            "name": "skyscraping",
            "engagements": []
        }, {
            "name": "tennis",
            "engagements": [{
                "name": "engagement346",
                "members": [{
                    "id": "34",
                    "account": {
                        "id": "3546"
                    },
                    "position": {
                        "id": "3999434",
                        "positionTitle": "abc"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Juicing",
            "engagements": [{
                "name": "347343",
                "members": [{
                    "id": "4546",
                    "account": {
                        "id": "3545"
                    },
                    "position": {
                        "id": "35006",
                        "positionTitle": "abc"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Instead it is the same as above, just without the initial line,

```
"name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas":
```

so it is:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1",
            "members": [{
                "id": "e334",
                "account": {
                    "id": "eefe"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3434",
                    "positionTitle": "abc"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "landscaping",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1343",
            "members": [{
                "position": {
                    "id": "4545",
                    "positionTitle": "abc"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement346",
            "members": [{
                "id": "34",
                "account": {
                    "id": "3546"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3999434",
                    "positionTitle": "abc"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Juicing",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "347343",
            "members": [{
                "id": "4546",
                "account": {
                    "id": "3545"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "35006",
                    "positionTitle": "abc"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: You are mapping through the `engagementAreas` array so your function will not return anything that's outside of that array.

Comment: You could use object.assign or spread operator to achieve your desired result, like `{ ...realGraphData, engagementTypes: /*your previous map here*/ }`

Comment: @Icepickle would I use this in conjunction with what I already have?

Comment: @Sparlarva I added an answer that should hopefully answer your question and your comment question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` or the spread operator to achieve a full copy with the updated properties, an example of this code would be the following

```
const updatedGraphTable = { ...graphData,
  engagementAreas: graphData.engagementAreas.map(area => ({ ...area,
    engagementTypes: area.engagementTypes.map(type => ({ ...type,
        engagements: type.engagements.map(engagement => ({ ...engagement,
          members: engagement.members.map(member => ({ ...member,
            position: { ...member.position,
              positionTitle: 'abc'
            }
          }))
        }))}))
    }))
  };
```

This doesn't make the code very readable, but it would be a one line conversion. The spread operator will copy all properties of the object, and then we overwrite the existing properties by redefining them

```js
const graphData = {
  "name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
      "id": "1",
      "engagementTypes": [{
          "name": "forestry",
          "engagements": []
        },
        {
          "name": "houses",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1",
            "members": [{
              "id": "e334",
              "account": {
                "id": "eefe"
              },
              "position": {
                "id": "3434",
                "positionTitle": "Manager"
              }
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "landscaping",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1343",
            "members": [{
              "position": {
                "id": "4545",
                "positionTitle": "Senior Manager"

              }
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "community days",
      "engagementTypes": [{
          "name": "skyscraping",
          "engagements": []
        },
        {
          "name": "tennis",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement346",
            "members": [{
              "id": "34",
              "account": {
                "id": "3546"
              },
              "position": {
                "id": "3999434",
                "positionTitle": "Ultime Manager"
              }
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "Juicing",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "347343",
            "members": [{
              "id": "4546",
              "account": {
                "id": "3545"
              },
              "position": {
                "id": "35006",
                "positionTitle": "Senior Ultimate Manager"

              }
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const updatedGraphTable = { ...graphData,
  engagementAreas: graphData.engagementAreas.map(area => ({ ...area,
    engagementTypes: area.engagementTypes.map(type => ({ ...type,
        engagements: type.engagements.map(engagement => ({ ...engagement,
          members: engagement.members.map(member => ({ ...member,
            position: { ...member.position,
              positionTitle: 'abc'
            }
          }))
        }))}))
    }))
  };
  
console.log( updatedGraphTable );
```

Comment: My aim is to try and assign the positionTitle within this object the data from an array which contains the same 'positionTitle' field.. such as.. positionTitle = IndividualData.positions[i].positionTitle;  Would this still work with this solution?

Comment: Sure, I just set it as you had suggested with abc, you have the member at that time, so you could map it from there

Answer (score 1):

`map` creates a new array that is a transformed input array. What you are mapping over is `realGraphData.engagementAreas` so you get a transformed version of it.

## Edit:

For this kind of tasks is better to use some library that helps with manipulating objects like `ramda` or `lodash`.

```js
function main() {
  const spec = {
    engagementAreas: [{
      engagementTypes: [{
        engagements: [{
          members: [{
            position: {
              positionTitle: () => "abc"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  };
  const result = transform(spec, graphData);
  console.log(result);
}


const graphData = {

  "name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
      "id": "1",
      "engagementTypes": [{
          "name": "forestry",
          "engagements": []
        },
        {
          "name": "houses",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1",
            "members": [{
              "id": "e334",
              "account": {
                "id": "eefe"
              },
              "position": {
                "id": "3434",
                "positionTitle": "Manager"
              }
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "landscaping",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1343",
            "members": [{
              "position": {
                "id": "4545",
                "positionTitle": "Senior Manager"

              }
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "community days",
      "engagementTypes": [{
          "name": "skyscraping",
          "engagements": []
        },
        {
          "name": "tennis",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement346",
            "members": [{
              "id": "34",
              "account": {
                "id": "3546"
              },
              "position": {
                "id": "3999434",
                "positionTitle": "Ultime Manager"
              }
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "Juicing",
          "engagements": [{
            "name": "347343",
            "members": [{
              "id": "4546",
              "account": {
                "id": "3545"
              },
              "position": {
                "id": "35006",
                "positionTitle": "Senior Ultimate Manager"

              }
            }]
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const transform = R.curry((spec, objOrArray) => {
  const mapWithIndex = Array.isArray(objOrArray)
    ? R.addIndex(R.map)
    : R.mapObjIndexed;
  return mapWithIndex((value, key) => {
    const fnOrSpec = typeof key === "number" ? spec[0] : spec[key];
    if (fnOrSpec) {
      if (typeof fnOrSpec == "function") {
        return fnOrSpec(value);
      }
      return transform(fnOrSpec, value);
    }
    return value;
  }, objOrArray);
});

main();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Map returns an array of results. You are handing it everything inside of "engagementAreas".
Instead try only passing  the array to your function and setting the "engagementAreas" part of your object to the returned value