# Objects data to be updated with value from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to update the 'positionTitle' field of my graphData object with the 'positionTitle fields of my individualData array.

I need to do it accurately, both sets of data have 'accounts' which both have the same id and fullname for user, I was hoping to try and use this to do the matching.

I want the positionTitle's from the users with same account id or name (whichever is easier) to go into the objects fields.

This is currently what I have:
My Object (that i want to update):

```
graphData = {

"name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement1",
          "members": [{
              "id": "e334", "account": {
                  "id": "eefe", "fullName": "jim bean"
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3434",
              "positionTitle": "Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "landscaping",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "engagement1343",
    "members": [{
        "id": "e334", "account": {
            "id": "123", "fullName": "john boer"
        },
      "position": {
        "id": "4545",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Manager"

      }
      }]
     }]
    }
   ]
},

{
"name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement346",
          "members": [{
              "id": "34", "account": {
                  "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO", "fullName": "edy long"
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3999434",
              "positionTitle": "Ultime Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "Juicing",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "347343",
    "members": [{
        "id": "4546", "account": {
            "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF", "fullName": "jeff bint"
        },
      "position": {
        "id": "35006",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Ultimate Manager"

      }
    }]
}]
 }]
}]
}
```

My array whose positionTitles I want to take:

```
IndividualData = [{
  "account": {
    "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
    "fullName": "jeff bint"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy",
    "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2016-10-07",
    "endDate": null
  }]
}, {
  "account": {
    "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
    "fullName": "edy long"
  },
  "positions": [{
    "id": "a160X000004nKfhQAE",
    "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
    "organizationName": "a",
    "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
    "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
    "isPrimary": true,
    "startDate": "2018-03-05",
    "endDate": null
  }]
},  {
    "account": {
      "id": "123",
      "fullName": "john boer"
    },
    "positions": [{
      "id": "325345634634",
      "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
      "organizationName": "a",
      "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
      "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "startDate": "2018-03-05",
      "endDate": null
    }]
  }

]
```

The function I'm currently using, which does take the first positiontitle field of the array:

```
  const updatedGraphTable = { ...graphData,
        engagementAreas: graphData.engagementAreas.map(area => ({ ...area,
          engagementTypes: area.engagementTypes.map(type => ({ ...type,
              engagements: type.engagements.map(engagement => ({ ...engagement,
                members: engagement.members.map(member => ({ ...member,
                  position: { ...member.position,
                    positionTitle: IndividualData[0].positions[0].positionTitle
                  }
                }))
              }))}))
          }))
        };


  console.log(updatedGraphTable)
  console.log('a' + JSON.stringify(updatedGraphTable))
```

my expected result with the positions updated:

```
updatedGraphData = {

"name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement1",
          "members": [{
              "id": "e334", "account": {
                  "id": "eefe", "fullName": "jim bean"
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3434",
              "positionTitle": "Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "landscaping",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "engagement1343",
    "members": [{
        "id": "e334", "account": {
            "id": "123", "fullName": "john boer"
        },
      "position": {
        "id": "4545",
        "positionTitle": "Managing Director"

      }
      }]
     }]
    }
   ]
},

{
"name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement346",
          "members": [{
              "id": "34", "account": {
                  "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO", "fullName": "edy long"
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3999434",
              "positionTitle": "Managing Director"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "Juicing",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "347343",
    "members": [{
        "id": "4546", "account": {
            "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF", "fullName": "jeff bint"
        },
      "position": {
        "id": "35006",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"

      }
    }]
}]
 }]
}]
}
```

My current result:

```
{
"name": "Annual meetings",
"engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1",
            "members": [{
                "id": "e334",
                "account": {
                    "id": "eefe"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3434",
                    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "landscaping",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement1343",
            "members": [{
                "position": {
                    "id": "4545",
                    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
    }, {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "engagement346",
            "members": [{
                "id": "34",
                "account": {
                    "id": "3546"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "3999434",
                    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Juicing",
        "engagements": [{
            "name": "347343",
            "members": [{
                "id": "4546",
                "account": {
                    "id": "3545"
                },
                "position": {
                    "id": "35006",
                    "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

Comment: ...And your code?

Comment: Hi it's   <'the function i'm currently using'> , above.  The current output it gives me is the last part.

Comment: So, I get that it differs from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257476/object-formatting-map-is-removing-my-first-line), but only slightly, as you have `member.account.id` that you can search inside your individual positions, I am just not sure where your problem might be

Comment: @Sparlarva ah ok, sorry. Overlooked it, sitting in a wobly train

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the trick would be to first map your data into an object (so you don't have to search over both arrays all the time), and then conditionally set the value (as I saw that your first manager, doesn't really have a matching position).

So to create the dictionary for usage in your later model, you can first do

```
// first map the accountId to positions
const accountIdToPositionDict = individualData.reduce( (current, item) => {
  current[item.account.id] = (item.positions.filter( position => position.isPrimary )[0] || {} ).positionTitle;
  return current;
}, {} );
```

This would then have an object where `accountIdToPositionDict["123"]` would be `Managing Director`, and then change the duplicating logic into:

```
const updatedGraphTable = { ...graphData,
  engagementAreas: graphData.engagementAreas.map(area => ({ ...area,
    engagementTypes: area.engagementTypes.map(type => ({ ...type,
        engagements: type.engagements.map(engagement => ({ ...engagement,
          members: engagement.members.map(member => ({ ...member,
            position: { ...member.position,
              // use the found positionTitle, or the original one that was given
              positionTitle: member.account &&  accountIdToPositionDict[member.account.id] || member.position.positionTitle
            }
          }))
        }))}))
    }))
  };
```

Where the position would then be set based on the found accountId in the dictionary, or the original title if no match was found

```js
const individualData = [{
    "account": {
      "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF",
      "fullName": "jeff bint"
    },
    "positions": [{
      "id": "a16b0000004AxeBAAS",
      "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
      "organizationName": "a",
      "positionTitle": "Senior Manager, Energy",
      "positionLevel": "5-Middle Management & Advisers",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "startDate": "2016-10-07",
      "endDate": null
    }]
  }, {
    "account": {
      "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO",
      "fullName": "edy long"
    },
    "positions": [{
      "id": "a160X000004nKfhQAE",
      "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
      "organizationName": "a",
      "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
      "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "startDate": "2018-03-05",
      "endDate": null
    }]
  }, {
    "account": {
      "id": "123",
      "fullName": "john boer"
    },
    "positions": [{
      "id": "325345634634",
      "organizationId": "001b0000005gxmlAAA",
      "organizationName": "a",
      "positionTitle": "Managing Director",
      "positionLevel": "4-Head of Business Unit/Head of Region",
      "isPrimary": true,
      "startDate": "2018-03-05",
      "endDate": null
    }]
  }
];

const graphData = {
"name": "Annual meetings",
  "engagementAreas": [{
    "id": "1",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "forestry",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "houses",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement1",
          "members": [{
              "id": "e334", "account": {
                  "id": "eefe", "fullName": "jim bean"
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3434",
              "positionTitle": "Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "landscaping",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "engagement1343",
    "members": [{
        "id": "e334", "account": {
            "id": "123", "fullName": "john boer"
        },
      "position": {
        "id": "4545",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Manager"

      }
      }]
     }]
    }
   ]
},

{
"name": "community days",
    "engagementTypes": [{
        "name": "skyscraping",
        "engagements": []
      },
      {
        "name": "tennis",
        "engagements": [{
          "name": "engagement346",
          "members": [{
              "id": "34", "account": {
                  "id": "0010X000048DDMsQAO", "fullName": "edy long"
              },
            "position": {
              "id": "3999434",
              "positionTitle": "Ultime Manager"
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
 {
  "name": "Juicing",
  "engagements": [{
    "name": "347343",
    "members": [{
        "id": "4546", "account": {
            "id": "001b000003WnPy1AAF", "fullName": "jeff bint"
        },
      "position": {
        "id": "35006",
        "positionTitle": "Senior Ultimate Manager"

      }
    }]
}]
 }]
}]
};

// first map the accountId to positions
const accountIdToPositionDict = individualData.reduce( (current, item) => {
  current[item.account.id] = (item.positions.filter( position => position.isPrimary )[0] || {} ).positionTitle;
  return current;
}, {} );

// then use it in the mapping function
const updatedGraphTable = { ...graphData,
  engagementAreas: graphData.engagementAreas.map(area => ({ ...area,
    engagementTypes: area.engagementTypes.map(type => ({ ...type,
        engagements: type.engagements.map(engagement => ({ ...engagement,
          members: engagement.members.map(member => ({ ...member,
            position: { ...member.position,
              // use the found positionTitle, or the original one that was given
              positionTitle: member.account &&  accountIdToPositionDict[member.account.id] || member.position.positionTitle
            }
          }))
        }))}))
    }))
  };
  
console.log( updatedGraphTable );
```

Comment: Thanks for your post again icepickle, i'm just working I'll come back to it in the morning. again, thank you.

Comment: There is something that I missed out - in the individualsData, some employees have multiple positions, their positions are titled as "isPrimary":true, or false, within the positions object, if they have multiple positions the primary position is the one I want to use?

Comment: Yes so currently on my larger data set, it's not taking the primary position when the use has multiple positions

Comment: @Sparlarva as you can see from the map, it does have a check to only get the positions that have `isPrimary` and in case there are more primaries, it would take the first. You could print the `accountIdToPositionDict` to see if there is something wrong there?

Comment: I want to take the primary position for each user from the individualData and assign it to all positions for a user in the graph data (primary and non primary), the difficulty is that a non-primary position for the user in both the individual data and graphData have the same position IDs so i dont think it would work updating the fields using the position ID?

Comment: Should I create an new question for it?

Comment: & if there is no primary position then use the first position

Comment: @Sparlarva this addition of small extra requirements and create new questions for each of them, makes me think that you do not wish to think about your problem. Clearly you haven't really thought your ideas through, and you seem to be unable to update simple logic to fit in newer requirements. Every one of your last 4 questions are nearly identical questions, with minimal changes in requirements, and to be honest, at some point, you need to learn how to do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
accountPositions = {};
IndividualData.forEach((data) => {
    accountPositions[data.account.id] = data.positions.filter((pos) => {return pos.isPrimary})[0].positionTitle;
});

    graphData.engagementAreas.forEach((area) => {
        area.engagementTypes.forEach((type) => {
            type.engagements.forEach((engagement) => {
                engagement.members.forEach((member) => {
                    if (!accountPositions[member.account.id]) return;
                    console.log('position updated from ', member.position.positionTitle, 'to', accountPositions[member.account.id]);
                    member.position.positionTitle = accountPositions[member.account.id];
                });
            });
        });
    });
```